# MacVim + Skim + latexmk Setup

Tags: latexmk, vim, vim-latex

How do I setup MacVim + Skim PDF Viewer on macOS? I have searched online for various guides but I end up getting extremely confused. I'm relatively new and have only used Overleaf in the past but due to size constraints, I feel the need to compile locally. I have a Macbook Pro running Catalina. The goal is to set it up as Ms. Diana Cai did here: https://www.dianacai.com/blog/2018/06/28/latex-vim-skim-setup/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @DG' I am having lots of trouble setting up MacVim and Skim PDF viewer on my Macbook Pro running Catalina. I was wondering if anyone could guide me?

Comment: "Lots of trouble" is very vague. What exactly isn't working? Please be more specific! What have you tried so far?

Comment: To be clear: Did you use the `.vimrc` linked in the post you mentioned above?

Comment: @DG' I have downloaded MacVim as well as Skim but integrating the two as well as adding/finding the .vimrc file is super confusing. I'm super inexperienced with this type of stuff lol I'm sorry if I'm not really that clear.

Comment: The simplest "integration" is just to use Skim in auto update mode, so that it refreshes the view of the PDF whenever you compile Latex.  What I do in MacVim is `:!xelatex %` , then `:!open -a Skim %:r.pdf`.    It is a good idea to use MacVim with as little customization as possible until you get the hang of it.  But if you want a sensible starting place, try https://github.com/tpope/vim-sensible